# all concept need to have for a beginner development realtime operating system

Tags: operating-system, real-time

I am a beginner in development realtime operating system (RTOS). I want to study with concepts in the OS first. I also tried to search the list of concept need to know for development a RTOS. I don't think, I will develop new rtos in this time. I only want understand a realtime. Something like https://github.com/TrampolineRTOS/trampoline